# setting low values to zeros in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a following list of arrays:

```
[array([  2.64161017e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.61751972e-16]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ -5.84525493e-01,   1.68725948e+00,   3.57918637e-17]), array([  3.25845641e+00,  -1.96333607e+00,  -1.99522910e-16]), array([ 3.42568843,  0.92118282,  1.67971424]), array([ 3.4257338 ,  0.92122015, -1.67966083])]
```

I have tried to replace all small values by zeros:

```
Tab[np.abs(Tab)<0.0000001] = 0
```

However, my way of solving this problem failed and I am getting the error in return:

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

How can I set elements to zero if they are below a specific threshold?

Comment: `Tab` doesn't seem to be an array. (What you've posted doesn't look like a data structure at all; whatever it is, it's not `Tab`.)

Comment: It's a list of arrays

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Lists of arrays don't support the operation you're trying to perform. Lists of arrays are generally only useful as an intermediate representation while you're building up an array incrementally; they should be converted to arrays once you want to start operating on the data.

Comment: I understood my mistake and the problem is solved. Thank you for pointing it out.!